# sum of normal conditional distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, conditional-probability, mean

I know that given $X$ and $Y$ being independent variables and both coming from normal distributions, then $Z=X+Y$ also comes from a normal distribution.

I was wondering if If I have two conditional distribution $P(Z|X)=N(z; \mu_{X}, \Sigma_{X})$ and $P(Z|Y)=N(z;\mu_{Y},\Sigma_{Y})$, and I define some distribution $Q(Z)$ as 
$Q(Z)=\frac{1}{2}(P(Z|X) + P(Z|Y)) $

Is $Q(Z)$ also normal?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear since it seems like OP is perhaps confusing sum of random variables and sum of densities (or cdf:s).  The result in the first paragraph concerns a random variable $Z$ defined so that it's realization is always the sum of the realization of $X$ and the realization of $Y$.  I don't think there's any meaningful way to "sum" random variables conditional on different information; and your notation looks like a mixture of distributions rather than a sum of random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% on your notation, so let me know if I'm not fully answering your question. You can't really "add distributions", you can only add random variables, so I'm guessing when you add the distributions, you are talking about the random variables.

Yes, you answered your own question, to see this just define $Z_Y \sim P(Z|Y)$ and $Z_X \sim P(Z|X)$.

Both are normal, and hence, following from the fact that

[Z is normal if X and Y are normal and Z = X + Y],

the sum of $Z_X$ and $Z_Y$ is also normal (any scaling, the $\frac{1}{2}$, will also not affect that).

The technical term is that the Normal distribution is closed under conditioning (and summation)

Comment: Thanks. I believe that answered my question. I wasn't sure about "you can't really add distributions" part.

Comment: You cannot perform P(X) + P(Y), you can only perform X + Y, is what I meant